# I'm trying to select an element I'm working with:

Tags: javascript, selenium, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver

So, written code looks like this:

```
IWebElement Enter = webDriver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Enter"));
```

Im trying to get grab a Enter txt from code:

```
<li>
  <a onclick="javascript:var p;if (document.getElementById('chckPot').checked==true){p=1;}else{p=0;};waitScreen();window.open('frmnewname.aspx?mod=0&amp;pot='+p,'mojframe');" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-folder-open">;</i>
    Enter
  </a>
</li>
```

So what ever I do I get the following error-message :

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with LinkText == Enter
```

Code for test is written in C#, and previous version of app has a ID but new one don't have it (look in code).

Comment: alecxe answer should work. Here's your code - `IWebElement Enter = webDriver.FindElement(By.LinkText("; Enter"));`. If you try to print the text of the anchor element you will see both the semicolon and Enter text as the Enter text is a separate node in your element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would approach this using xpath:

```
IWebElement element = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(), 'Enter')]"));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working, partial and linktext dont, dont know why really. and i tryed before i post here. Actually i tryed and i tryed before i post here, but i was wrong with someting, this helped.

Comment: Code was changed, and i lost "id" and some kind recognition, but only now like i written above :D

Answer (score 1):

*Partial* link text may help here (there could be extra newlines and spaces):

```
IWebElement Enter = webDriver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("Enter"));
```